# SQL Server: Sum distinct multiple columns except one without using nested/sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that produces following result:

**SQL Server Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT com.CompanyID,c.Category,p.ModelNo,p.ProductCode,sum(sipl.SubTotal) AS Qty
FROM    SalesInvoiceProductsList AS sipl 
        INNER JOIN SalesInvoice AS s ON sipl.SalesInvoiceID = s.SalesInvoiceID 
        INNER JOIN Product AS p ON sipl.ProductID = p.ProductID 
        INNER JOIN Company AS com ON p.CompanyID = com.CompanyID 
        INNER JOIN Category AS c ON p.CatID = c.CatID
WHERE  (s.DateSold ='2019-02-04')
GROUP BY  p.ModelNo,sipl.SubTotal,p.ProductCode,com.CompanyID, c.Category
order by com.CompanyID
```

**Query Result**

```
CompanyID      Category          ModelNo    ProductCode       Qty
---------------------------------------------  -------------------

Gree        Fridge Invertor        1105        ghi             2
Gree        Fridge Invertor        1105        ghi             6
PEL         AC Invertor            1103        abc             1
```

I want the following result but without using nested/sub queries because nested select statements gives an error on date formatting for unknown reason while using with `RDLC report of C#`. So in short, i need following result without using nested `select` statements

**Desired Result**

```
CompanyID      Category          ModelNo    ProductCode       Qty
---------------------------------------------  -------------------

Gree        Fridge Invertor        1105        ghi             8
PEL         AC Invertor            1103        abc             1
```

Following query produces the desired result but gives formatting error on date when using with `C# RDLC`.

**Unwanted query which uses multi select statements**

```
SELECT b.CompanyID, b.Category, a.ModelNo, a.ProductCode, a.Qty
FROM     (SELECT s.DateSold, p.ProductID, p.ModelNo, p.ProductCode, SUM(sipl.SubTotal) AS Qty
          FROM SalesInvoiceProductsList AS sipl 
          INNER JOIN SalesInvoice AS s ON sipl.SalesInvoiceID = s.SalesInvoiceID 
          INNER JOIN  Product AS p ON sipl.ProductID = p.ProductID
           GROUP BY p.ModelNo, p.ProductCode, p.ProductID, s.DateSold) AS a 
INNER JOIN
           (SELECT DISTINCT p.ProductID, p.CompanyID, cat.Category
            FROM  Product AS p 
            INNER JOIN Category AS cat ON p.CatID = cat.CatID 
            INNER JOIN Company AS c ON p.CompanyID = c.CompanyID) AS b ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID

group by  b.CompanyID, b.Category, a.ModelNo, a.ProductCode, a.Qty,a.DateSold 
having a.DateSold = '2019-02-04'
```

Comment: Your first query does not "work" since you are attempting to sum sipl.SubTotal but you also include that column in the group by clause. You have a fundamental flaw in that query. Adding DISTINCT to it was a kludge to fix it but it did not work. Gordon fixed that without specifically saying so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to fix the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT com.CompanyID, c.Category, p.ModelNo, p.ProductCode,
       sum(sipl.SubTotal) AS Qty
FROM SalesInvoiceProductsList sipl JOIN
     SalesInvoice s
     ON sipl.SalesInvoiceID = s.SalesInvoiceID JOIN
     Product p JOIN
     ON sipl.ProductID = p.ProductID 
     Company com
     ON p.CompanyID = com.CompanyID JOIN
     Category c
     ON p.CatID = c.CatID
WHERE  s.DateSold ='2019-02-04'
GROUP BY com.CompanyID, c.Category, p.ModelNo, p.ProductCode
order by com.CompanyID
```

Comment: sorry i forget   sum(sipl.SubTotal) gives unnecessary sum for particular where clause conditions.

Comment: where s.DateSold='2019-03-15' produces result Qty= 3,4,2,2 while correct result is Qty=3,2,1,1

Answer (score 0):

Use a window function instead of group by:

```
SELECT DISTINCT com.CompanyID,c.Category,p.ModelNo,p.ProductCode,
       SUM(sipl.SubTotal) OVER(PARTITION BY p.ModelNo, com.CompanyID,c.Category,p.ModelNo,p.ProductCode) AS Qty
FROM    SalesInvoiceProductsList AS sipl 
        INNER JOIN SalesInvoice AS s ON sipl.SalesInvoiceID = s.SalesInvoiceID 
        INNER JOIN Product AS p ON sipl.ProductID = p.ProductID 
        INNER JOIN Company AS com ON p.CompanyID = com.CompanyID 
        INNER JOIN Category AS c ON p.CatID = c.CatID
WHERE  (s.DateSold ='2019-02-04')
order by com.CompanyID
```